# Need to dynamically list the next coming days/dates in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, appointment

As part of my job, I'm in charge of working on my organizations website (built using Squarespace).

What I gotta do, right now, is simplify an appointment form so that customers can only pick a day in the current week, with the idea they can turn up for the appointment any time as long as its on the day they've chosen.

Obviously, if you know Squarespace, its scheduling options doesn't allow me to remove choosing appointment times (by duration in minutes) so I decided to create a new application form from scratch.

So I'd have the user choose the appointment day from a dropdown menu here.

```
<select id="day" name="name">
  <option>Monday</option>
  <option>Tuesday</option>
  <option>Wednesday</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

But my boss wants the menu to display these days along with their corresponding dates (i.e. Monday 24th, Tuesday 25th, etc.)

I know JavaScript is the only way I can properly program a menu like this so here is what I want.

- A dropdown menu that displays the next 7 or so days, including today
- Each option must display the day of the week along with the corresponding day and month (i.e. Monday 17th January)
- It must only display Weekdays and Saturdays. Sundays must NOT be displayed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another snippet delivering 6 date options, starting with today:

```js
const td=new Date();               // set Date object td to today
const opts=[...Array(7)].map(_=>{  // generate an Array of 7 (empty) elements
 let r=td.toLocaleString("en-us",{weekday:"long",month:"short",day:"numeric"}); // format date td
 td.setDate(td.getDate()+1);       // increment td by one calendar day
 return r                          // return date string to opts array 
}).filter(d=>!d.match(/^Sun/))     // remove the Sunday from the array

document.querySelector("select").innerHTML=opts.map(o=>`<option>${o}</option>`).join("") // make options
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some codes, that loops through next 7 days and eliminates the Sundays, hope it helps !

```js
let today = new Date(); // get Today date
let dropDownMenu = document.getElementById('day');

for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){ // Looping through 7 next days
    let newDate = new Date()
    newDate.setDate(today.getDate() + i); 
    if(newDate.getDay() === 0){ 
        continue; // Eliminating the Sunday
    }
    else{ 
      let dayText = document.createTextNode(Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}).format(newDate)); // Formating the date the way you want before appending into option Element
      let dayOption = document.createElement('option')
      dayOption.append(dayText);
      dropDownMenu.append(dayOption);
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="day" name="name">
  
</select>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, you have to provide some context behind your answer not only code. I'd advise you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your snippet worked perfectly! Although, I decided to use Squarespace's forms instead of my custom code but it still worked. Although, how can I remove the first two options in my dropdown menu (which is the default option I can't delete and a black one)? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't clearly understand what you are trying to say, but to delete first two options in my snippet, you can change that in the loop code to make it start from 3rd day, i = 2 instead of i = 0

Comment: Okay. To reiterate, I am using Squarespace which the website I'm working on is built from. Originally, I was creating a new form from scratch with raw HTML code but I decided to just use the form creation tool Squarespace provides for better ease. I was able to use your JS snipper to add those days to a dropdown menu in the form. When making a dropdown menu, it has an option by default but it's still there in the top of the menu when I add the extra days so I want to get rid of it. But I don't want to get rid of any of the added days.